# Implement SSE (Server Sent Events) with File Upload to ASHX Handler

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I want to implement the following:

1. Call an ASHX hanlder from UI using Jquery.
2. Upload a file to this ASHX handler.
3. And when upload is complete, I want to keep sending messages from the server to UI (SSE) to tell the user about the execution status of the code in ASHX handler.

I am stuck with the 3rd point that has been mentioned above.

Following is the UI code that I have written:

```
     var file = $("input#importFileInputHidden")[0].files[0];
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('file', file);

     importAjaxCall = $.ajax({
        xhr: function () {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            $('#progressBar').show();

            //Method to show the progress of the file being uploaded
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = Math.round((evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100);
                    $('#percentageImportComplete').text('' + percentComplete + '%');
                    $('#importStatus').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                }
            }, false);

            return xhr;
        },
        type: 'post',
        url: "Handler.ashx",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            //Some code to show success status to user
    });
```

How to capture the messages I am sending from the server?

Comment: Have you even tried this ? `complete: function (a,b,c) {
                    //console.log(a);
                    //console.log(b);
                    //console.log(c);
            }`

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: how did you solved this requirement, Praveen? I'm facing the same request ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried to look into responseText property of http request?

```
success: function () {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
    });
```

Comment: Hi.. Yes, I tried the above but the "success" is executed only when the HTTP request is completed. In my case I want to keep pinging the UI about the execution status of the HTTP request. How to achieve this..??

Comment: If the request is completed how can you return some messages to the ui? i'm not sure if this can be done in some way..